# Predefined type CallSite is defined in multiple locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, appharbor, ironjs

I get errors from both build and website precompile on App Harbor that seem to originate from multiple versions of the C# dynamic assemblies. They both start with warnings that look like:

```
2>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'd:\temp\qb3ydb5o.xoq\input\packages\IronJS.Core.0.2.0.1\lib\net40\Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll' [D:\temp\qb3ydb5o.xoq\input\...csproj]
```

The build passes, but website precompile has these warnings but fails:

```
(0): error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember'
d:\temp\qb3ydb5o.xoq\output\_PublishedWebsites\...cshtml(4): error CS1969: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
```

I wonder if it has anything to do with how IronJS is packaged? Can someone help me troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by removing references to `Microsoft.Scripting.Core` and `Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute`. These were added by the IronJS NuGet package. I still have AppHarbor build errors, but those are because AppHarbor isn't doing a clean build (different problem).

**Edit**: I submitted an issue with IronJS: https://github.com/fholm/IronJS/issues/92